# Set data groups in load method

Tags: c3.js

How can data be grouped in load method? When you group data in generate method its working perfect. Example of grouping in generate method:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', -30, 200, 200, 400, -150, 250],
            ['data2', 130, 100, -100, 200, -150, 50],
            ['data3', -230, 200, 200, -300, 250, 250]
        ],
        type: 'bar',
                    groups: [
                        ['data1', 'data2']
                    ]
    },
    grid: {
        y: {
            lines: [{value:0}]
        }
    }
});
```

But, in my application names of data is generated dynamically so data must be grouped in load method where I receive the `JSON` from the web service.
Example:

```
chart.load({
    json: dataJsonGraph,
    bindto: '#chart'                    
});
```

I've tried adding data groups in this way

```
chart.load({
    json: dataJsonGraph,
    bindto: '#chart',
    data: {
        groups: [
            ['dynData1', 'dynData2']
        ]
    }                       
});
```

but its not working at all...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same problem as you.  To solve it, I used `chart.group()` after calling `chart.load()`.

```
chart.load({
    json: dataJsonGraph,
    bindto: '#chart'                    
});

chart.groups([ 
    ['dynData1', 'dynData2']
]);
```